# Why is the field through this cylinder non-symmetric?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, particle-physics, gauss-law

I don't understand why I can not apply Gauss' law to this object. Is it not cylindrically symmetric?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because the cylinder is of finite length, rather than infinite length.  As a result, the fields lines are not always radial from the cylinder: near the edge of the cylinder the field lines will have some components along the axis of the cylinder.  Thus, it is not possible to find a surface on which the field has constant magnitude, i.e. in the integral $\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec S$ 
$$
\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec S \ne \vert \vec E\vert \oint dS
$$
meaning one cannot recover $\vert \vec E\vert$ from 
$$
\vert \vec E\vert \ne \frac{q_{encl}}{\epsilon_0 S}
$$
with $S$ the surface of the Gaussian surface.